# PySerial not able to read LoRa E5 Mini responses

Tags: python, pyserial, lora

When I try to read data off of a microcontroller using PySerial, I get no response with the following code (a LoRa-E5 mini is atttached to my UART COM5 Port)

```
import serial
import time

print("serial test")
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port = 'COM4'

ser.open()
print(ser.is_open)

ser.write("test".encode())
print("data received")
time.sleep(1)
numlines = 0

while True:
    try:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        decoded_bytes = float(ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8"))
        print(decoded_bytes)
    except:
        print("Keyboard Interrupt")
        break


ser.close()
```

I just need to be able to read the data off of the LoRa E5 mini.

What could be done to remedy my probem?

Answer (score 0):

Could be problem be that you read from the serial port line by line? Does your application in LoRa-E5 serial sends a line ending with `\n`?

You do not send line endings characters, and you open the serial port without timeout, which will result in the `readline` command blocking forever.

See [readline doc](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports).

> readline() reads up to one line, including the \n at the end. Be careful when using readline(). **Do specify a timeout when opening the serial port otherwise it could block forever** if no newline character is received. If the \n is missing in the return value, it returned on timeout.

Default serial port parameters [class serial.Serial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial)

> **init**(port=None, baudrate=9600, bytesize=EIGHTBITS, parity=PARITY_NONE, stopbits=STOPBITS_ONE, **timeout=None**, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, write_timeout=None, dsrdtr=False, inter_byte_timeout=None, exclusive=None)

- **timeout = None**: wait forever / until requested number of bytes are received

Answer (score 0):

What you're not getting is how the LoRa-E5 is working: its AT firmware doesn't just spit out whatever it receives, but uses AT commands, and outputs hex-encoded strings. In the case of LoRa P2P, aka in the LoRa-E5 AT firmware "Test Mode", when the module receives a string it outputs `+TEST: RX` , followed by hex-encoded bytes. For instance, if you sent `012345`, the incoming string will be `+TEST: RX 303132333435`.

So you need to take the hex part, decode it and THEN do your `decoded_bytes = float(...)`.

And because it is AT firmware, sending meaningless strings like "test" won't do anything (especially when not terminated by CR/LF). If you want to make sure it is alive, send `AT\r\n`. You should at least then get a response: `AT+OK\r\n`.